# Set up an identity matrix using a vector of vectors C++

Tags: c++, vector

Part of a program I am writing requires me to set up a vector of vectors, to be a square matrix of dimensions 5. There seems to be no output when trying to print out the vector and I don't know why. Any tips?

```
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int rows=5;
vector< vector<double> > identity; // declare another vector of vectors, which         initially will be
// the identity matrix of the same dimensions as 'matrix'.

    for (int j=0; j<rows; j++) {//set up the identity matrix using the Kronecker Delta     relation. If row == col, then =1. Else =0.
        vector<double> temp2; // temporary vector to push onto identity
        identity.push_back(temp2);
        for (int k=0; k<rows; k++){
            if(j==k) {
            temp2.push_back(1);
            }
            else {
            temp2.push_back(0);
            }
        }
        identity.push_back(temp2);
    }
    // print out identity
    for (int j=0; j<identity.size(); j++) {
       for (int k=0; k<identity[0].size(); k++) {
           cout<<' '<<identity[j][k];
       }
       cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you pushing `temp2` onto `identity` twice?

Comment: Oops, I'll check that now. EDIT: That works, I knew I must have been being stupid somewhere. Cheers :)

Comment: That's your bug.  `identity[0].size()` was 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    vector<double> temp2; // temporary vector to push onto identity
    identity.push_back(temp2);
    for (int k=0; k<rows; k++){
        if(j==k) {
        temp2.push_back(1);
```

When you push temp2 into your top-level vector, it is *copied*.
Changing temp2 afterwards has no effect on that copy, which is owned by the identity vector.

Now, you *do* push temp2 *again* after populating it, but the first item in identity will be a default-initialized vector with zero size. The structure you're actually populating looks like this:

```
 {{},
  {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {},
  {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
  {},
  {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
  {},
  {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
  {},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

So, your loop

```
for (int j=0; j<identity.size(); j++) {
   for (int k=0; k<identity[0].size(); k++) {
```

will never do anything, because `identity[0].size()` is always zero.

---

tl;dr:
just remove the first `identity.push_back(temp2)` line.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I understand why it didn't work now.